# URL rewrite in subfolder css not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How are you today,
I have a problem in url rewriting..

I Upload my website on `pesco` sub-directory, Like `www.example.com/pesco` and my css path like this `/css/style.css` but when site run css must be like `www.example.com/pesco/css/style.css` but my css showing like this `www.example.com/css/style.css` url rewrite missed the `pesco` sub-directory

Please any one give me the solution

My Code is below you can see.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /pesco/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^index.html index.php
RewriteRule ^aboutus.html aboutus.php
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ products.php?catid=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ detail.php?category=$1&product=$2
```

Comment: Have you tried `./css/style.css`?

Comment: with `./css/style.css ` its work fine. but if I want to work without starting dot, than how to managed it for example I would like to use as `/css/style.css`

Comment: But if it's working, why do you need to remove the dot? That fixes your issue...

Comment: `but when site run css must be like www.example.com/pesco/css/style.css` Why? This just needlessly duplicates the resource. Why not reference `/css/style.css` and be done with it?

Comment: my site url is `www.example.com/pesco` but in source code my css and js files path like this `/css/style.css` But when we open css file via url, url must be `www.example.com/pesco/css/style.css` than css file can run

Comment: So just put the `./` it fixes your problem and is valid

Comment: `url must be www.example.com/pesco/css/style.css than css file can run` it doesn't *have* to be that way. You could do it the correct way and do `<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/style.css'>`. It's going to work from any page on the site.

Comment: if when I move to my all site sub-directory to root directory, again I will changed `./ to /` in all files. Its not valid answer for me...

Comment: `/` will *always* work on that domain. What you are trying to do is unnecessary.

Comment: I want to do I run site on sub-directory for client checking, when client checked the site, after that I will move the site on root directory.

Comment: my website url is `http://www.majid-sports.com/pesco/` you also can see css and js files in `view-source:http://www.majid-sports.com/pesco/`

Comment: OK, I think I understand, but why does the CSS have to reside in `/pesco/` if it's the same in `/css/style.css`? If it's a temporary thing anyway? But I see what you mean now

Comment: @MrTom `./` and `/` would work on the root fine, you won't need to change them

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is just a reference problem. You can try `./css/style.css` as this means it looks to find `css` as a directory inside the same directory as the file requesting it, whereas `/css/style.css` is essentially looking in the `root` directory